# Python django with multiple submit buttons

Tags: python, html, button, submit

I have the below code in my python django template HTML.
I am expecting these submit buttons to come in line like ( GUI   BOOT).
But now i am getting in different rows like shown below.

GUI

BOOT

Functionalities of the buttons are fine.Only appearance in not correct.

```
        <form action="Action_1" method="post">{% csrf_token %}&emsp;&emsp;<input id="Serial_no" type="hidden" name="Serial_no" value="{{device.Serial_no}}"><input type="submit" value="GUI"></form>
        <form action="Action_2" method="post">{% csrf_token %}&emsp;&emsp;<input id="Serial_no" type="hidden" name="Serial_no" value="{{device.Serial_no}}"><input type="submit" value="BOOT"></form>
```

Please help me on this to get the submit buttons in line

Comment: At first you should fix your obviously faulty HTML.

Comment: stackover flow is not allowing me to put the exact html here.So edited it so that I can put in the question.HTML is working fine for me.My issue is submit buttons are not coming in line ...its coming like its stacked...

Comment: You have to format it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your input buttons are nested in a form element. Knowing that a form element is of type block, you won't be able to have both your buttons on the same line without applying some CSS rules.

In your case, I suggest you display your forms as inline-blocks using the following CSS rule:

```
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to learn more about block and inline elements, I suggest you have a look at the w3schools HTML tutorial: [HTML Block and Inline Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp).

Also, if you don't know where to put your CSS rule for a Django template, here is the Django documentation regarding static files: [Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Just added  the following line in html page and its working fine                                                   <style>  form { display: inline; }  </style>

Comment: It’s a good thing it works, however I would recommend you to put all your CSS rules in a separate CSS file rather than adding them into the Django template.